# NET CORE - Error uploading files through DOCKER + LINUX + STORAGE WINDOWS

Tags: ubuntu, docker, docker-compose

I have the following problem.

When trying to upload a file to my api (net core 3.1) that runs on docker on a Linux machine, and the storage where I need to save these upload files and I get an access denied error.

`Access to the path '/shared/xxx/xxxx.pdf' is denied. 2023-10-19 16:50:50  ---> System.IO.IOException: Permission denied`

The storage runs on Windows, and both machines are in the Windows AD domain

Docker Compose

```
version: '3.5'  
volumes:
 storageCM:
  driver_opts:
   type: cifs
   o: "username=*****,password=*****,vers=3.0,domain=contoso.net"
   device: "//192.168.52.20/shared"   

services:
 api-netcore:   
    image: image_container:3410
    platform: linux
    container_name: container_xxxx
    restart: always 
    volumes:
        - storageCM:/shared
    ports: 
        - '8000:80'
```

The username and password that I use on the volume has full access to the Windows storage.

I've already done tests mapping through Samba directly to the docker host, but the same error occurs.

According to the docker composer above, when trying to upload the api inside the container it shows the error

```
Access to the path '/shared/xxx/xxxx.pdf' is denied.
2023-10-19 16:50:50  ---> System.IO.IOException: Permission denied
```

When I save it to the host machine it works normally and when I save it from the host machine to the Windows storage it also works.

The error is only inside the container